# Finding Indexes For A Table in Sybase

Tags: sql, environment-variables, sybase, indexing

I am currently working in an environment where I am made double blind.

1. I have to email any queries I need to run to a employee of the client
2. That employee runs them in a SAS client, with an odbc connection to SyBase

I need to find out how to ascertain exactly what indexes exist on a specific table.  I would use `sp_helpindex`, but apparently it doesn't exist on their instance of SyBase.

We *believe* that it is SyBase 12, but again I can't be certain of anything.

Does anyone have SQL for...
- Confirming exactly what version of SyBase we're working on?
- The details of all indexes that exist for a given table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "Confirming exactly what version of SyBase we're working on?"

Why not use:

> select @@version

---

Sybase website is down (at least here), but it would be something like:

```
IQ SHOW INDEXSET INDEXES
```

or

```
IQ SHOW INDEXSET FOR indexset
```

where `indexset` is `tablename` because every table has a indexset assigned with the same name.

If you have access to sybase website possibly you can go further :)

Comment: Thanks for this, though it appears that it's failing due to other system SPs being missing.  I guess my client would prefer me to simply *use the Force* :)

Comment: @Dems yep it's what I though it would happen ^^ But do you know which version is?

Comment: Nearly 5 hours to find out, but I got it!  `Sybase IQ/12.7.0/100114/P/ESD 9/Enterprise Linux64 - amd64,Opteron64,X86_64/2.4.21-27.0.1.ELsmp/64bit/2010-01-14 10:20:04`

Comment: @Dems check my update, it woulb be something like that I presume.

Answer (score 3):

Most Sybase products have a -v command line argument to tell the version with or without the engine running.

To find the indexes on any table enter the following, where `my_table` is your table's name:

```
select i.name 
from sysindexes i, sysobjects o
where o.name = 'my_table'
  and o.id = i.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
select i.name 
from sysindexes i, sysobjects o
where o.name = 'table_name' and i.indid >=1
and o.id = i.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Find Indexes on multiple tables, not like image indexes

```
select name = o.name,iname = i.name from sysindexes i, sysobjects o where o.name in ('table1','table2','table3') and i.name not like 't%' and i.indid >=1 and o.id = i.id
```

Answer (score 0):

For sybase version:

```
select @@version
```

in Sybase version SAP IQ/16, you can get list of indexes with following (table name my_table is case sensitive:

```
select *
from sys.sysindexes
where tname = 'my_table';
```

Answer (score 0):

`select * from sys.sysindexes where tname='Your Table name'`

Try the above code, it worked for me.